# Docker Overlay Network, Port Connections not in netstat visible

Tags: docker, port, overlay, netstat

I'm playing with Docker Swarm, trying to understand the IPv6 problem for Docker Swarm and overlay Network, when i found a strange behaviour.

netstat should show all the connections, but on a docker overlay network published port, then endpoint connection is not shown.

Work to reproduce:

- Install two Server with Docker
- Install Docker and initialize Docker Swarm
- Create an Overlay Network
- Deploy nginx on the overlay network and publish port 80

  docker network create --driver overlay nginx
  docker service create --name my-nginx --publish target=80,published=80 --network nginx --replicas=2 nginx

Then Connect from any Client to the webserver created with netcat:

```
nc 10.0.2.34 80
```

Check the netstat output on both sides:

Client:

```
[root@docker1 centos]# netstat -ano | grep 80
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.208:39924        10.0.2.34:80      ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
```

on Server:

```
[root@docker2 centos]# netstat -ano | grep 80
tcp6       0      0 :::80                 :::*                    LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
```

You will not see the connection that has been established by the Client.
But the connection is working, I can get the main page from nginx.

Can anyone explain this?